# How to create a list item in a separate site collection using 2013 workflows and SPD?

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, sharepoint-designer

How can I, using sharepoint designer, create a 2013 workflow that creates list items in other site collections than the one that the workflow was initiated in?

I have read that it is possible with REST but that requires an access token and the difficulty level to do this (imo) simple thing got very high.

Is there any other way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if there are another methods to achieve your task. However, we have a scenario where we create Work spaces in different web applications from another web application using workflow. To make it clear, web application 1  will create site collection in either web application 2 or web application 3 at run time, when work flow is approved. We achieve this by calling web service. It is a visual studio created workflow.

Comment: Do you know how do it on practice?

Comment: We did using custom workflow and server side code. Using SPD you must be able to use rest services. Not tried it myself